# Rest-Client HK2 failure detected

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, rest-client

Im developing a "ManageYourAnime/Manga/Movies/TvShows/Whatever"-Program. A friend had the idea/need and im now making it for him as it´s a good opportunity to learn things and produce something somewhat useful, to at the very least a single person in the world.

Anyways, i found out that myanimelist.net provides a restservice where you can search for animes or mangas specifically and then optain infos such as a description, alternate names, episode count, artwork, etc. And i want to use that in my application.

It already sort of works. I had it downloading artwork images, but it was painfully slow sometimes and the window was not responding until the request was complete, so i put it into a seperate thread (seems MUCH faster in postman). It works, sort of, but i do get this message every time `Response response = builder.get();` is called within the thread here.

```
public void run() {
            String encoded = null;

            try {
                encoded = URLEncoder.encode(search, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(encoded != null) {
                Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
                client.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(accountName, password));
                client.register(JacksonXMLProvider.class);
                WebTarget target = client.target(String.format("%s%s", "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=", encoded));;
                Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
                Response response = builder.get();
                if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                    results = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<MyAnimeListEntity>>() {});
                }
                client.close();
            }

            controller.done();
        }
```

This is the error i get.

```
Mar 22, 2018 7:36:08 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 failure has been detected in a code that does not run in an active Jersey Error scope.
WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2316)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$3.run(Utilities.java:1378)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$3.run(Utilities.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getAllConstructors(Utilities.java:1374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findProducerConstructor(Utilities.java:1317)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:148)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.initialize(MessageBodyFactory.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory$MessageBodyWorkersConfigurator.postInit(MessageBodyFactory.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.lambda$initRuntime$2(ClientConfig.java:470)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:470)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:319)
    at contentdownloader.GetXmlFromRestController$runner.run(GetXmlFromRestController.java:111)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 44 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider
    contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter,javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=14
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=138770088
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.initialize(MessageBodyFactory.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory$MessageBodyWorkersConfigurator.postInit(MessageBodyFactory.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.lambda$initRuntime$2(ClientConfig.java:470)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:470)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:319)
    at contentdownloader.GetXmlFromRestController$runner.run(GetXmlFromRestController.java:111)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Now it DOES still work, but i don´t know what to do about this still. I kinda feel like im doing something im not supposed to do this way. I really just don´t exactly get what this means right now and would be very glad if someone could explain it, even though it technically does the thing regardless.

Those are the dependencies i use for the request, might be useful to know.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I fixed it now, all i had to do was adding javax.activation V1.1.1 to the maven dependencies. Somehow thought it was more. Wonder what it needs it for considering it ran without anyways.

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

- shelve all your changes or stash them
- switch branch to master : `git fetch && checkout master`
- restart your system
- mvn clean install
- cd ./target/
- java -jar .\a**SNAPSHOT.jar
- invalidate cache and restart